# Can Anyone Explain These Long Network Stalled Times?

Tags: cordova, mobile

I am experiencing some incredibly long load times for server requests but only when I am accessing the resources via my mobile network.

I discovered the issue when I was testing out a mobile app I've built with phonegap on an Android device. On WiFi the images and API from the server load super quick. The server is high spec, with caching and cloudflare is used as a CDN. Response times over WiFi are practically instant.

However on my mobile network, I am seeing that there is significant load times, which seem to be caused by "stalling"

[image: Screenshot of Network tab from Chrome Inspector]

As can be seen in the screenshot above, some of the load times for images is over 1 minute! This is amazing me as the images are a mere 2kb-5kb in size at most

According to the chrome debug tool, this is caused by "stalled"

[image: Close up of the network stalling]

Here is the headers of the request for an image. Again you can see the image is tiny, it's been served by cloudflare and has hit the cloudfare cache.

[image: Headers of the image request]

This issue isn't just occuring for the images, it's also happening when the app is requesting a JSON from the server as well.

Could it be possible that my mobile network is being throttled? I've been testing with some other apps and I have noticed there is a delay loading images and resources as well. I have also uploaded the app to the web and accessed it that way to rule out it if was a phonegap issue but resources are still stalling for ages before being loaded.

I have checked with other people's phones on a different mobile network and their doesn't appear to be any issues (they are running iOS however).

Perhaps my theory is correct and my mobile network is being throttled (and only allowing x number of connections at a time and stalling me) or is there something else at play here which I may be missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

> Perhaps my theory is correct and my mobile network is being throttled (and only allowing x number of connections at a time and stalling me) or is there something else at play here which I may be missing out on?

@robobobobo,

Welcome to mobile computing. It has been this way since day one. As long as the big mobile providers play there games, this will go on. In short, the big mobile providers believe in big salaries and get the last bit of value from all legacy systems. I've been doing the Internet since 1995, not much has changed - as far as sabotaging the competition.

Can you fix it? No.
Can thing be done? Yes, build smarter Apps.

Best of Luck
Jesse

Comment: I guess I've just been lucky up until now! I've recently moved city so I suspect my mobile network is now on a different setup and explains the slower speeds. I'll just have to get smarter at apps like you said, though I had thought I was doing relatively well!

Comment: Step #1 figure out which assets should load locally - like images, customer id, last transactions, etc. Start with the things that will change the least - javascript libraries, images, HTML & CSS. Also, keep in mind that Google and Apple, now allow some asset loading in the field, but that should be reserved for hot updates - like security fixes. Best of Luck